# ng-material-treetable Showing error in Angular Application

Tags: angular, tree

I am trying to integrate ng-material-treetable in angular application.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-material-treetable
but its showing error like,

```
core.js:15723 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.
```

but i have added  `BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule` in app.modules.ts only. [image: Error]

after searching in search engine got some ideas, following link https://angularscript.com/angular-material-tree-table-component/ also not working same error.

Package.json for reference.

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.5",
        "@angular/cli": "^7.2.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^11.1.1",
        "@types/c3": "^0.6.0",
        "@types/chartist": "^0.9.37",
        "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.10",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.3.6",
        "@types/node": "^8.10.43",
        "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~1.7.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "^5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "typescript": "~3.1.1"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The developer is importing BrowserModule into his package.  an Angular application can only contain one import (https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#should-i-import-browsermodule-or-commonmodule).  If you look at his repo, the dev has already been notified:  https://github.com/mlrv/ng-material-treetable/issues/17

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. so can you suggest me angular tree table example.